# How can I split long posts into pages?

Tags: pages

I want to make one long post, but have it paginate. I read that you could add this: `<!--nextpage-->`, but all it did was hide the content under the tag. Is there a plugin that helps do this? Is it possible that my theme may not allow this?

Comment: There is an easier way, you can just install a plugin. You might find this video useful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3oFZOA9stE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your theme must have support for the `<!--nextpage-->` tag.

You will need to add `<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>` in your post loop.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the code in my theme's post loop, do I need to add it anywhere else?

Comment: No, as long as it's present on your single template.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my template blocks it since pages aren't showing up. Thanks for your answer though.